# Odoo 10 getting the id of the selected value of many2one

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I have this many2one field that I want to get the ID of the selected value

```py
service = fields.Many2one('mainservices.mtvehlog', string='Select Service(s)')
```

so onchange i want to know the id and do something after knowing (I want to make other fields invisible)

What if the many2one is multi selection? How do you get the ID's that have been selected?

```py
@api.depends('service')
def _compute_hide(self):
    source_obj=self.pool.get('mainservices.mtvehlog').browse(self.service)
    if source_obj == '1':
         self.services_selected = source_obj
         self.hide = True

    else:
         self.services_selected = source_obj
         self.hide = False
```

kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In compute methods using depends decorator always loop throuth self first.

```py
   for rec in self:
           # and this is how you get the id value 
           #you don't have to browse you have direct acces to properties of the selected value
           if rec.service.id  == somthing :
           # and you will not get except singlton error
```

you question is not clear what you want to do with the id value exactly.

Comment: I would love to make certain element inivisible also what if its a multi selection Many2one,How do you get the Ids of the selected values??

Comment: So how do you make fields invisible if an id is found in     rec.many2many_fiels.ids    ,Sure I will up vote it